# TypeScript Factory Subclass is not Assignable to Type Superclass

Tags: typescript, generics, reflection, factory

I want to use the [Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) using TypeScript to convert raw data into a `User`.  I have two different types of `User`s: `Employee` and `Customer`.  Both extend the base class and compile without problems.  Below is an extremely simplified version of these three classes.

```
abstract class User {
  constructor(data: any) { }

  static createFromServer<T extends User>(this: new (...args: any[]) => T, data: any): T {
    return new this(data);
  }
}

class Employee extends User {
  static '@type' = 'Employee';

  static createFromServer<T extends User>(this: new (...args: any[]) => T, data: any): T {
    return new this(data);
  }
}

class Customer extends User {
  static '@type' = 'Customer';

  static createFromServer<T extends User>(this: new (...args: any[]) => T, data: any): T {
    return new this(data);
  }
}
```

Simple enough.  Now for the Factory.  I want to create a Factory that will take raw data returned from the server and convert that data into something the rest of the system can use (i.e. an instance of `User`).  What I *want* to do is something like

```
class UserFactory {
  /**
   * Vends a User constructed from the raw data from the server.
   *
   * @param userData (Object) - the User definition, as obtained from the server
   *
   * @return (User) the User initialized from `userData`
   */
  static vend<T extends User>(userData: any): T {
    switch (userData['@type']) {
      case Employee['@type']:
        return Employee.createFromServer(userData);

      case Customer['@type']:
        return Customer.createFromServer(userData);

      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown User type.');
    }
  }
}
```

As you can probably guess (since I'm here and not relaxing over the weekend), that doesn't work.  I get the following error:

> Type 'Employee' is not assignable to type 'T'.

Since `T` extends `User` and `Employee` extends `User` without adding or removing *anything* (in this simplified version), it seems like the above *should* work.  What's more annoying is it seems the above will work in other languages (e.g. Java (tested), C++), I'm just not sure why it won't work in this situation.

Somebody on GitHub suggested that the problem might be with [overloading the constructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7955), but clearly that's not occurring here.

So, why isn't `Employee` assignable to type `T`?  (How) can I get the above to work?  Is there a better way to handle this in TypeScript?  A correct answer will answer at least the first 2 questions.

### Addendum

`createFromServer()` is redefined in subclasses for a reason.  This is a minimally reproducible example.  The constructors don't actually take the raw data from the server.  Instead the `createFromServer()` converts the raw data into arguments the constructors can understand.

Answer (score -1):

I can't speak to the specific reason why TypeScript won't correctly infer the type, however, casting to any does allow the code to compile and for type inference to work correctly. eg.

```
class UserFactory {
    /**
     * Vends a User constructed from the raw data from the server.
     *
     * @param userData (Object) - the User definition, as obtained from the server
     *
     * @return (User) the User initialized from `userData`
     */
    static vend<T extends User>(userData: any) : T {
      switch (userData['@type']) {
        case Employee['@type']:
          return <any>Employee.createFromServer(userData); // Cast

        case Customer['@type']:
          return <any>Customer.createFromServer(userData); // Cast

        default:
          throw new Error('Unknown User type.');
      }
    }
  }

// Tests
const employee = UserFactory.vend<Employee>("");
employee.customerId = 7; // Error
employee.employeeId = 7;

const customer = UserFactory.vend<Customer>("");
customer.customerId = 7;
customer.employeeId = 7; // Error


// Added id properties to Employee and Customer
  abstract class User {
    constructor(data: any) { }

    static createFromServer<T extends User>(this: new (...args: any[]) => T, data: any): T {
      return new this(data);
    }
  }

  class Employee extends User {
    static '@type' = 'Employee';
    public employeeId : number;

    static createFromServer<T extends User>(this: new (...args: any[]) => T, data: any): T {
      return new this(data);
    }
  }

  class Customer extends User {
    static '@type' = 'Customer';
    public customerId : number;
    static createFromServer<T extends User>(this: new (...args: any[]) => T, data: any): T {
      return new this(data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not working because you've written too much code. You should be leveraging polymorphism. What this means is simply removing the static factory methods from the two base classes.

That way will work as you expect and you will have less code to maintain. In fact, it's the very reason why the static method in the `User` class has a `this` type and `new`s the containing class using the `this` reference. It enables derived classes to inherit a factory that intrinsically has their more derived type

Also this isn't Java. In fact I couldn't think of a language less like Java than TypeScript

Comment: Remember, this is an extremely simplified version of the real code.  I don't show the real reason I'm doing a lot of things.  The `createFromRequest()` methods naturally look very different in the subclasses as the raw data from the server looks very different and the constructors don't actually take the raw data as its argument (why even use factories in that case?).

Comment: @c1moore plenty of reasons, for example the constructors themselves could be doing the actual work. At any rate, if that is the case you could make this work simply by removing the type constraints and the return type annotations.

Comment: Yet in the extremely simple case of `class MySet extends Set { add(myElement: MyElement): MySet;` I still get the message about "type MySet is not assignable to type 'this'".

Comment: @torazaburo I don't know what the `Set` class in your code is (it's not an ES2015 Set since it's not generic) but it sounds like you should be specifying the return type as `this`.

Comment: Yes, it needed to be have a return type of `this` as you say. As an aside, apparently TypeScript, at least the version of TS and typings that I am using, accepts non-generic `Set` and interprets it as `Set<any>`.

Comment: Interesting. That's weird. Unless there is a default generic, that should trigger a syntax error. Regarding the return type. The reason you have to specify `this` is because that is what the base `Set<T>`, in `lib.es2015.d.ts`, specifies it and using a less specific type breaks that contract

Comment: yep. don't set those factories as static properties on the class... you'll run into chicken egg  problems.